# concatenated string from php to js using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What is wrong here:

```
function getoptions(){
    echo "<option value = 3>ABX</option>";
}

...
$id = $db->lastInsertId();  // for example `10`
$options = getoptions();
echo ($id . '***' . $options);
```

**js**

```
console.log(data);
```

Result:

```
<option value = 3>ABX</option>10***
```

I'm expecting `10***<option value = 3>ABX</option>`

Any help?

Comment: You need to `return` not `echo` the output of the function otherwise it is echoed when called

Comment: @Tristan, but I'm using `getoptions()` on another places and need the `echo`. Now I tred `echo` and `return` together - doesn't work - result is messed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use the same function to either echo or return the output you can pass a flag to the function. You can set a default value so the function performs as expected by other parts of your app.

```
// set default value of echo the output so it's non-breaking for other functions that require the output to be echoed
function getoptions($out = 'echo'){
    if ($out == 'return') return "<option value = 3>ABX</option>";
    echo "<option value = 3>ABX</option>";
}

...
$id = $db->lastInsertId();  // for example `10`
$options = getoptions('return');
echo ($id . '***' . $options);
```

Comment: wait, pls, it seems I need two functions - first - `function getoptions($out = 'echo')` and second - `function getoptions($out = 'return')` ?

Answer (score 0):

In function `getoptions` you are `echo`ing, you need to return the value. Look at the corrected function below.

```
function getoptions(){
    return "<option value = 3>ABX</option>";
}

...
$id = $db->lastInsertId();  // for example `10`
$options = getoptions();
echo ($id . '***' . $options);
```